# Were days ever written as ordinal numbers when writing day-month-year?

Tags: writing-style, numbers

I know that the day is written as a cardinal number (1, 2, 3) and not an ordinal number (1st, 2nd, 3rd) in the day-month-year and the month-day formats. But was there ever a time when ordinal numbers were used instead? I remember writing April 2nd, 2019, etc. and I'm curious what happened.

Comment: You are incorrect, ordinal numbers are used today more often than cardinal numbers.

Comment: Being a graduate of the University of Louisville, I have to favor Cardinal numbers, but I still would prefer to refer to today as "April tooth".

Answer (score 7):

Dates written with ordinal numbers have always been less common than dates written as cardinal numbers in the month first format. Here is a Google Ngram for the phrases "July 4th" and "July 4":

[image]

The curves look slightly different for British versus American English, but the predominance of cardinal dates (when writing the month first) remains the same. I don't know about Canadian, Australian and other varietes of English, as Google Ngram Viewer doesn't allow to select them.

The Ngram for the day first format (i.e. "4 July" and "4th July") shows that in this convention, cardinal numbers have replaced ordinal numbers in the 1940s. Before that, ordinal numbers were the norm:

[image]

But this apparent current predominance of cardinal dates (in both month first and day first formats) may be misleading, because the picture changes slightly when you consider where and how dates are written. If you write a date in a common date format, such as "April 26, 2003", current stlye guides recommend that you write cardinal numbers, but they allow that you pronounce these as ordinal numbers. For example, the *Chicago Manual of Style* recommends:

> When specific dates are expressed, cardinal numbers are used, although these may be pronounced as ordinals.

And as soon as you write dates outside of strict date formats, for example when you narrate what happened on the last Independence Day, you will most probably write about the "Fourth of July", not "July 4", so while strictly speaking "fourth" is a word and not a number, it is a word that means a cardinal number. So cardinal numbers are still in use for dates today.

But you ask about the past, and indeed the convention for dates was different a few decades ago. Many of us will remember learning to write "August 2nd" in school (and not "August 2"). For example, the *Collins Cobuild English Grammar* of 1990 recommends:

> Ordinal numbers can be written in abbreviated form, for example in dates or headings or in very informal writing. You write the last two letters of the ordinal after the numbers expressed in figures.
>
> - …on August 2nd

The change from the recommendation of ordinal dates, as in the 1990 *Collins Grammar*, to a preference of cardinal dates must have taken place before the turn of the millennium, because *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* from 2002 states (p. 1719) that

> [i]n recent times the versions … with cardinal numbers have become increasingly favored over those with ordinals.

This seems to contradict the change in the 1940s apparent in the Ngrams of the day first format. But then, grammars and style guides are always a bit behind actual usage, so that the 1990 Collins Grammar was merely continuing to recommend a tradition that unnoticed by its authors had already fallen out of use.

---

I would like to note that contrary to what @Chenmunka claims in their comment, British English doesn't universally follow the day before month convention. As the Wikipedia article on [Date and time notation in the United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_the_United_Kingdom) states:

> The month-first form (for example "December the third") was widespread until the mid twentieth-century, and remains the most common format for newspapers across the United Kingdom.

A screenshot from the *[Times](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/)* website provides proof:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Amazing. Now I understand what happened. I'm glad you thought about it before.

Comment: In British English you would say *4th July*, not *July 4th*.

Comment: @Chenmunka Not generally, no. See my edit. From Wikipedia: "The month-first format is still spoken, perhaps more commonly when not including a year in the sentence, but is now less frequently used. "

Comment: I don't know if using the 4th of July is the best example.  _Of course_ that's going to be more prominent in US English than UK, simply because it's a major holiday in the US.  You might see the reverse effect with, e.g. the 5th of November in the UK.  (Though _V for Vendetta_ may have spoiled that on both sides of the Pond.)  Picking a date that has no special significance in either country might give you more even results.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman November 5 turns out the exact same graphs: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=5th+November%2C5+November&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C5th%20November%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C5%20November%3B%2Cc0 and https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=November+5%2CNovember+5th&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNovember%205%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNovember%205th%3B%2Cc0 (as does any other date).

Comment: Hmm, playing around with that, I discovered there's a recent uptick if you put in e.g. "5th of November", as opposed to just "5th November".  (Change the end-date to 2019 instead of 2000).  There is some some variation when picking significant dates, possibly not enough to be statistically significant.  (Wish there was a way to tell ngrams to search for ANY date in each format instead of doing 365 individual searches...)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Ah, didn't even notice that the default graphs end at 2000. You can download the raw data from https://books.google.com/ngrams/datasets and write some data mining algorithm in your favourite programming language, if you feel bored ;-) But note that with "5th of November" you no longer have a common date format, but a textual representation of how a date would be spoken, which follows other rules.

Comment: " strictly speaking "fourth" is a word and not a number, it is a word that means a cardinal number" Actually an ordinal number, right?

Comment: Excellent answer. My question is whether "4 July" includes, for instance, "14 July" as well? Or, does "july 4" include "July 4th"?

Comment: The ngram evidence presented here is unconvincing, I think you need to address some of the possible variables here including how other issues could be skewing these numbers. For example "4th July" would likely be a British way to say something, but most Americans would say "4th of July", so you need to aggregate at least the variations "Fourth of July" and "4th of July" in your results to play on even ground with "4 July". Additionally I think the number-month name search is likely skewed by results that aren't strictly actually dates.

Answer (score 3):

Many people in Britain still write dates as ordinal numbers. I share a classroom with another teacher who absolutely insists on students writing them as ordinal numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That's good to know.